# Wit.ai - 'Thank you’ being detected as search query always. Even after training it for entity

Tags: wit.ai

I have created a new app in wit.ai. In stories, I have created entity with different intents. Here I used 'Thank you' as a different intent. But when I send 'Thank you' to wit, it considers it as a search query instead of the entity which I created. I trained it for that entity in the 'Understanding tab. But still it is considering it as a search query. Like that for some other intent also, it considers as a search query only. What shall I do to make the 'Thank you' string as an entity instead of search query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using trait for "thank you" or freetext, keywords?

From Wit docs:

> " Only trait entities (like typically intent) have their value
>   influence the action prediction. For non-trait entities, the value is
>   ignored with regards to action prediction."

Also you can add restrictions in Actions tab to prevent undesirable function callings, if needed.